# Overflow and Z index issue

Tags: css, angularjs

Pop up is getting behind the parent division in the case of Overflow

```
<div class="layout">
    <div class="abc">
        <div ng-show="items" ng-repeat="item in items" class="pqr">
            <div class="item-class">
               <!-- ...some data... -->
               <span>{{item.name}}</span>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="pqr">
            <div class="item-class dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"> 
                 <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span> 
            </div> 
            <ul class="add-menu dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                <li>
                    <a ng-click="addItem1()">&nbsp;Add type 1</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a ng-click="addItem2()">&nbsp;Add type 2</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

> css

```
.layout{
    overflow-y: auto;
}
.abc {
    height: 600px;
    width: 200px;
    display: table-cell;
}
.pqr {
    height: 30px;
    width: 30px;
}
```

When more items are added to the layout container, it will give us a scroll in the vertical direction
But in the case, that the overflow occurs and the add icon is in the right corner, on hovering the plus icon, it will show the dropdown menu to the right side as a popup. But the pop up's half portion will be behind the parent divisions,
this occurs only in the case of overflow, otherwise, the popup is showing over all the items,

The code is not 100%, but added essential parts of the code.
Please help

Comment: Please add a mvce - https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Without having run the code, I can see you don't have any z-index specified like you mentioned in the title. Try setting the "z-index" CSS property (research what the default value is, and then set the z-index in your CSS to a larger number than the default, or otherwise set the z-index property on both your elements).

Comment: @PBJ it's not the problem with z-index value. I forgot to specify the z-index value here, but I've tried the same with a very larger value for the popup earlier, and it won't work